# Stuck on solving $\log x - 1 > \frac{2}{\log x}$

Tags: inequality, logarithms

I'm stuck in this 
$$\log x - 1 > \frac{2}{\log x}$$

The book solution is

> $$1/10<x<1$$
>   $$x>100$$

What I've tried so far:

**1<sup>st</sup> attempt**

> $$x>0$$

\begin{eqnarray}
\log^2x - \log x > 2 \\
\log^{2}x - \log x - 2> 0
\end{eqnarray}

So assuming

> $$T = \log x$$

$$T^2 - T - 2 > 0$$

\begin{eqnarray}
x1 = 2\\
x2 = -1
\end{eqnarray}

Substituting

> $$\log x=2$$

$$4 - 2 - 2 > 0 $$

Substituting

> $$\log x=-1$$

$$1 + 1 - 2 > 0 $$

**2<sup>nd</sup> attempt**

\begin{eqnarray}
\log x - \log 10 > \frac{\log 100}{\log x}\\
\\
\log \frac{x}{10} > \frac{\log 100}{\log x}\\
\\
\frac{x}{10} = \frac{100}{x}\\
\\
x^2=1000
\\
\end{eqnarray}

As you can see no one of attempts gave me a good results.

Comment: See also : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1880283/solve-the-inequality-xlog-2x2-le8

Comment: As a first (and possibly, main) step, can you solve $$t-1>\frac{2}t$$ for $t$ real?

Comment: Your first attempt is valid for $x>1$, for $0<x<1$ $\log x<0$ so, when you multipy by it you should reverse the disequality sign.

Comment: @Did Sorry for my very basic level: I'm not getting you.

Comment: @Did I meant (form my basic-ness side):Yes I can (probably wrong) $$x<-1$$ and $$x>2$$

Comment: No, the solutions are $t<-1$ **or** $t>2$.

Comment: @Did Yes, my bad. And was a word, not the logical operator. Thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following statements are equivalent:

- $\log x-1>\frac{2}{\log x}$
- $\frac{\left(\log x\right)^{2}-\log x-2}{\log x}>0$
- $\left[\left(\log x\right)^{2}-\log x-2\right]\log x>0$
- $\left(\log x-2\right)\left(\log x+1\right)\log x>0$
- $-1<\log x<0\vee\log x>2$
- $10^{-1}<x<10^{0}\vee x>10^{2}$

Comment: Thx. Sorry for bother you: steps 2->3 and 3->4 are not clear to me. Could you elaborate those two steps?

Comment: Do you agree/understand that the the quotient of two real numbers will be positive if and only if the product of these numbers is positive? That is $2\iff3$. Do you agree/understand that $y^2-y-2=(y-2)(y+1)$? That is $3\iff4$ (with $y=\log x$).

Comment: Totally agree. So it is crystal now. Thank you very much.

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

**Case** $\#1:$ If $\log x>0$

$$\log x-1>\dfrac2{\log x}\iff0<(\log x)^2-\log x-2=(\log x-2)(\log x+1)$$

$\implies$ either $\log x<-1$ which is impossible

Else $\log x>2\iff x>10^2$

**Case** $\#2:$ If $\log x<0,$

$$\log x-1>\dfrac2{\log x}\iff0>(\log x)^2-\log x-2=(\log x-2)(\log x+1)$$

$\implies-1<\log x<2$

But we already have $\log x<0$

$\implies-1<\log x<0\iff10^{-1}<x<10^0$

**Case** $\#3:$ What if $\log x=0$

Comment: Case #2 is wrong.

Comment: @Did,  Please find the updated answer

Comment: Yeah. Aligning $\implies$ and $\iff$ signs in such an uncontrolled way is bound to provoke such mistakes. To wit, one basically cannot be sure that your answer is now correct unless one performs the computations on one's side.